# Select multiple columns without multiple queries php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery, left-join

How do I join multiple table columns without multiple queries?
Is there a more efficient way to do this?
Table 1 and 2 will have over 3000 rows of data.

Table1

```
=========================================
ID    Name       skill   skill2   skill3
=========================================
1      Ed           1       4       3    
...
3000  Dave         200     500     345
--------------------------------------
```

Table2

```
=========================
ID     Skill Name
=========================
1        php
2        html
3        css
4        mysql
...
3000     python
-------------------------
```

E.G.

```
SELECT Table1.usrname,
(SELECT Table2.skillname FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.skill1 = Table2.Id) As skill1,
(SELECT Table2.skillname FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.skill2 = Table2.Id) As skill2,
(SELECT Table2.skillname FROM Table2 WHERE Table1.skill3 = Table2.Id) As skill3
FROM Table1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your method is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your method with correlated subqueries seems like a relevant approach at the problem. For performance, make sure that you have an index on `table2(id, skillname)` so the subqueries execute efficiently.

You might also want to try multiple joins:

```
select t1.username, t21.skillname skill1, t22.skillname skill2, t23.skillname skill3
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t21 on t21.id = t1.skill1
inner join table2 t22 on t22.id = t1.skill2
inner join table2 t23 on t23.id = t1.skill3
```

An upsvide of this approach is that you can easily get more columns from the skills table if neeed, as opposed to the inline subqueries you are using, which always return a scalar value.

If there may be missing skills, use `left join`s rather than `inner join`s.